# Google Cast: Load Metadata Error and No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present

Tags: android, stream, cors, google-cast

I try to cast a stream with my Android app.
The stream comes from a Sat-Receiver in my own network.
I access the stream over a http Link like:

```
http://192.168.188.23:8001/1:0:19:283D:3FB:1:C00000:0
```

When I open the stream in VLC i get this codec information:

> Type: Video /
>   Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) (h264)

In my app, I build this MediInfo:

```
private static MediaInfo buildMediaInfo(String title, String subTitle, String studio, String url, String imgUrl, String bigImageUrl, List<MediaTrack> tracks) {
    MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, subTitle);
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title);
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, studio);
    return new MediaInfo.Builder(url)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .setMediaTracks(tracks)
            .build();
}
```

The error Log from my Chromecast:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined  
[0.292s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS. player.html:1 
Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated. player.html:1  
[0.428s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://192.168.188.23:8001/1:0:19:283D:3FB:1:C00000:0:0:0:': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.  media_player.js:38 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.188.23:8001/1:0:19:283D:3FB:1:C00000:0:0:0:. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.gstatic.com' is therefore not allowed access. player.html:1  
[ 13.011s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:18
nb cast_receiver.js:18
kb.Yb cast_receiver.js:18
B.log cast_receiver.js:13
I cast_receiver.js:16
Z.ra cast_receiver.js:88
g.ra cast_receiver.js:53
Ib cast_receiver.js:23
Fb cast_receiver.js:24
(anonymous function) cast_receiver.js:21
e.onError player.js:53
K media_player.js:61
Ie.Ba media_player.js:117
R.yb media_player.js:67
pc media_player.js:34
h.dispatchEvent media_player.js:33
Hc media_player.js:39
Jc media_player.js:42
D.dh media_player.js:40
D.tf media_player.js:40
```

I am not able to change something at the stream itself.

Is that a problem in my code or a problem from my Sat-Receiver (the stream) & is there a solution when it is a problem from my Sat-Receiver?

**EDIT:**

after solve the CORS Problem new ERROR Log:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined
 [  0.280s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 player.html:1
Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated. player.html:1
 [  0.367s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://192.168.188.32/teststream1.php': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [ 12.071s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:18
 nb cast_receiver.js:18
 kb.Yb cast_receiver.js:18
 B.log cast_receiver.js:13
 I cast_receiver.js:16
 Z.ra cast_receiver.js:88
 g.ra cast_receiver.js:53
 Ib cast_receiver.js:23
 Fb cast_receiver.js:24
 (anonymous function) cast_receiver.js:21
```

**EDIT 2:**
The header from the stream look like this (capture with php):

```
[0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
[1] => Date: Sat, 04 Oct 2014 18:38:23 GMT
[2] => Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
[3] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u9
[4] => Connection: Close
[5] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[6] => Content-Type: video/mpeg
```

When I open the stream in VLC i get this codec information:

> Type: Video /
>   Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) (h264)

Android code same as above.

Receiver: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Simple-Receiver/blob/master/receiver.html

**EDIT 3**

With Custom Styled Adapter and optimzed Code:

Error Log Cast:

```
cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
undefined
 [405.177s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"currentTime\":0,\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"media\":{\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"duration\":0,\"contentType\":\"video\\/mpeg\",\"contentId\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.188.32\\/teststream1.php\",\"metadata\":{\"subtitle\":\"Auslandskorrespondenten berichten\",\"studio\":\"Das Erste HD\",\"title\":\"Weltspiegel\",\"metadataType\":1}},\"requestId\":2,\"autoplay\":true}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"229:de.resper.e2cast-22"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [405.187s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [405.193s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received cast_receiver.js:18
 [405.198s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event cast_receiver.js:18
 [406.017s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Now Casting: Weltspiegel\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [406.046s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load - contentId: http://192.168.188.32/teststream1.php autoplay: true time: 0 cast_receiver.js:18
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://192.168.188.32/teststream1.php': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 cast_receiver.js:55
 [408.624s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:18nb cast_receiver.js:18kb.Yb cast_receiver.js:18B.log cast_receiver.js:13I cast_receiver.js:16Z.ra cast_receiver.js:88g.ra cast_receiver.js:53Ib cast_receiver.js:23Fb cast_receiver.js:24(anonymous function) cast_receiver.js:21
 [409.519s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 229:de.resper.e2cast-22 cast_receiver.js:18
 [409.523s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"229:de.resper.e2cast-22","data":"{\"requestId\":2,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [410.301s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"setappstate\",\"statusText\":\"Ready To Cast\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a question in your post, so I am not sure what exactly you are asking; the error that you mention states that you are running into CORS issue which is required by chromecast (based on W3C requirements) and there is nothing you can do from the Cast SDK side to get around that.

Comment: I add the question above. So it is no problem from my app or from my cast receiver? On my Android Device i can play the stream without problems.

Comment: CORS is a requirement that needs to be satisfied for chromecast to play  your stream and usually that is added from the server that is serving the content. Once you pass that point, then one can see if there are other issues there or not but as of now, your first blocking issue is to fix the CORS issue. If you have control over the server that serves your content, you should be able to add the CORS headers

Comment: I was able to add CORS to the stream. Now I didnt get the CORS error anymore, but the Load Meta Data Error stay...

Comment: what receiver are you using?

Comment: this one: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Simple-Receiver/blob/master/receiver.html

Comment: That receiver won't be able to play live stream. I suggest you either ruse the Default receiver or the Styled receiver.

Comment: I switched to a default receiver, but i doesnt work and i cant connect to the debug console. Although I add EXTRA_DEBUG_LOGGING_ENABLED to the Builder:
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.EXTRA_DEBUG_LOGGING_ENABLED)
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(mApplicationId))
            .build();

Comment: If you want to debug the chromecast, you have to have either your own app Id, which means either having your own custom receiver app or create a Styled receiver; Styled receiver is almost identical in code with the default except that it provides some additional styling capabilities. Enabling logging should happen on the receiver side not on the sender; see the Debugging section here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver

Comment: Ok, I use now a Custom Style Receiver. I add the new Log File above. Same Error: Loading Meta Data Error